# Effect of pandas.DataFrame.sample() with frac set to 1

Tags: python, pandas

The call `ser = ser.sample(frac=1)` "shuffles" the data in series, meaning that

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | a |
| 3 | c |

now prints as:

| index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | c |
| 2 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 0 | a |

But has there been any change to the data or does this "shuffle" only matter when printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data has indeed been changed (permanently shuffled), but you will find that both the initial Series and the shuffled one are still equal:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"value": {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}}
)
print(df)
# Output
  value
0     a
1     b
2     c
3     d

df2 = df.sample(frac=1)
print(df2)
# Output
  value
1     b
3     d
0     a
2     c

print(df.eq(df2))
# Output
   value
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
```

That's because [pandas.DataFrame.eq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) (which is called when you run df == df2) *"unions mismatched indices together"*.

To avoid that, you have to reset the index after shuffling:

```py
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df.eq(df2))
# Output
   value
0  False
1  False
2  False
3  False
```